# computed value in vue wont load to template when value exist

Tags: vue.js

I have this issue i see first in vue. I have a computed property:

```js
numOfStudentsPerSubject() {
    let res = []

    for (let subject of this.subjects) {
        let key = subject.superSubject.trim()
        res[key] = 0
        for (let student of this.students) {
            let studentSubject = student.subjects.find((x) => x.superSubjectName === key)
            if (studentSubject) res[key]++
        }
    }
    console.log(res)
    return res
}
```

what is logged to the screen is the following result:

```
[Letters Recognition: 8, Listening - First Letter: 8, Listening - Letters: 0, Reading Comprehension - Sentences: 8, Reading Comprehension - Story: 8, …]
```

but when i try to pint data to the screen like :`<p>{{numOfStudentsPerSubject}}</p>`  it shows an empty array `[]` no matter what i do. anyone has any idea what can cause such an issue?

Answer (score 2):

First off you should be using an object for `res` and not an array. Arrays are indexed numerically and not by keys whereas objects are a collection of key value pairs.

Secondly, you are returning that array yet the Vue template is expecting a string so is just calling toString on the array which defaults to `[]` as you don't have any valid indexes to enumerate.

Switch to using an object and stringify that object (or use another method to convert it to a string) when you use it in the template.

```js
const obj = {
  'example1': 4,
  'example2': 7
}

console.log(obj.toString())

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: even if i change `return res` to `return '1'` it doesn't print anything